# Applying an aggregate function on an in-memory result set based on each row in it

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to generate a result set in two steps. The first step is simple and generates a base in-memory result set (let's call it `B`). In the second step, I need to add an additional column to `B` (let's call it `c`). For each row in `B`, `c` can be calculated by using an aggregate function on `B` based on the values of that row (this does look inefficient though).

The final result set is `B + c`. Results must be sorted by a column from `B` as well as the `c` column, so the whole thing should be a single query.

Getting `B` is simple, but how do I process it further based on its contents?

EDIT. Here's a table analogy to illustrate what I mean by "applying an aggregate function on `B` based on each row in `B`":

Say, we have a table `T` with a column `col`. Let's say that for each row in `T` we want to calculate the number of rows that have a higher `col` value. You could do it like this:

```
select
  t1.*, 
  (select sum(case when t2.col > t1.col then 1 else 0 end) from T t2) as count
from T t1
```

In my case the problem is that `B` is not a real table but an in-memory result set. How can I process it in a similar way?

Comment: Could you provide some basic example data, please? Is the query to be run on B in order to generate B + c?

Comment: I don't think data matters here - B can be any result set. Assume it's generated by a subquery in the main query - `(select whatever) as B`. I need to return B + c where for each row in B c is calculated based on other rows in B.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I've had another crack at it.

Answer (score 1):

OK - I'll give it another go.

Aliasing both the in memory results set and the columns that you need to use in that results set to derive c should work.

To continue your example from above:

```
select B.col,
(select sum(case when B2.col > B.col then 1 else 0 end) from (select whatever_col as col
from whatever_table) B2) as c
from
(select whatever_col as col from whatever_table) as B;
```

Let me know if I've got the wrong end of the stick again!

Comment: Thanks, but your example doesn't take into account the fact that `c` must be calculated for each row individually based on VALUES IN THAT ROW. I have added a simple example to the original question. I hope it will make things more clear.

Comment: Thanks again, but generating B is expensive. I can't afford doing it twice in the same query.

Comment: OK. If generating B is expensive then perhaps you could create a temporary table before running the query, populate that temp table with the in memory contents of B and then reference that temp table in the main query? You could then index the temp table to increase the efficiency of the main query. Other than that I'm outta ideas!